# Configuration to point an X tty to a separate system?

Tags: xorg, ssh, x11, tty, virtualization

Specifically, I have an Ubuntu 10.04 system with a headless Ubuntu 12.04 virtual machine, and I'm looking for a way to have it set up so pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> will take me into another X client which is connected to an X server on the VM (with `gdm` appropriately displayed at startup, etc.). As in, my startup script should spin up the headless machine and then immediately perform a `startx` pointed at the vm.

Answer (score 1):

If you enable XDMCP in the guest's DM then you can use `X :1 -query ...` in the startup scripts on the host to request a XDMCP connection to the X server running in the guest. This will open `:1` onto your guest, starting from the login screen. See the `Xserver(1)` man page for details.